# Is the equity ratio of US banks around 3%?

Tags: united-states, economics, banking

Did John H. Cochrane, a professor of economics at Chicago, [wrote](https://johnhcochrane.blogspot.com/2013/03/the-bankers-new-clothes-review.html):

> In order to make $100 of loans, a typical bank borrows $97—from
> depositors, from money-market funds, from other banks, or from
> bondholders—and sells $3 of stock, its "capital." So if only 4% of the
> bank's loans fail, the shareholders are wiped out, and the bank cannot
> pay its debts. Worse, if there is a rumor that some loans are in
> trouble, creditors may "run," each trying to get his money out first,
> and force a needless bankruptcy. Think of Jimmy Stewart in "It's a
> Wonderful Life."

[Putanumonit](https://putanumonit.com/2018/12/14/defense-of-finance/) claims on his blog that the 3% is wrong:

> As Cochrane was writing those words, in March 2013, the average equity ratio of US banks was 11.2%, up from 6% in the late 1980s.
>
> [...]
>
> Let me repeat that: economics professors who wrote a book about how raising equity ratios will solve the problem of financial crises got the actual equity ratio for banks, a number that is publicly reported and easily googlable, wrong by a factor of 4.

Does Putanumonit charge have merits or is there an apples-to-oranges comparison?

Comment: The blog posts does explain that the difference is the number is risk-weighted, which would explain these different numbers.

Comment: Unless "equity ratio" is something different from reserve ratio, the amount of money a bank must keep from each deposit is a regulated number. 10% I think.  Banks can only loan out up to $90 of every $100 in deposits.

Comment: @fredsbend the relevant regulations are Basel II (or maybe Basel III now), but those are incredibly complicated. And a large part of that is more individual weighting and rating of risks.

Comment: @MadScientist as per kh's comments on Cochrane's blog, the risk-weighting works in the *opposite* direction, and does *not* explain these different numbers. So Wells Fargo has an equity ratio of 11% on an unweighted basis, and a much *higher* number on a weighted basis.

Comment: @fredsbend you're comparing assets and liabilities. This question is about comparing equity and assets.

Comment: @energy I'm sure there's something I'm missing. Finance is not really a pet topic for me.

Comment: The first paragraph is basically utter nonsense.  It's literally financial gibberish and confuses the balance sheet financing with P&L statements.

Comment: The writer of the first paragraph I suspect is a communist, or pro communism.  That is the only rationale I can think of for being so financially illiterate.  It is readily apparent they never have even heard of loan loss reserves or capital stress testing. They have never worked for a bank, that's for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John Cochrane did not source his material well.  I suspected the numbers supplied by Putanumonit were sourced from capital stress testing that the Fed performs, and I was right. {I could not find the quarterly results which surely would have the number exactly}. It's from the [Comprehensive Capital Analysis and Review 2014: Assessment Framework and Results](https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/press/bcreg/ccar_20140326.pdf).

> As shown in figure A, the aggregate tier 1 common equity ratio of the 30 BHCs (ed. note from KDOG: Bank Holding Companies) in the 2014 CCAR (ed. note from KDOG: Comprehensive Capitals Analysis and Review, aka stress testing) has more than doubled from 5.5 percent in the first quarter of 2009 to 11.6 percent in the fourth quarter of 2013.1
>
> That gain reflects a total increase of more than $511 billion in tier 1 common equity from the beginning of 2009 among these BHCs to $971 billion in the fourth quarter of 2013.

Please note the almost perfectly aligned numbers which can be attributed to timing differences.

Comment: The John Cochrane quote is from his Wall Street journal review of Anat Admati and Martin Hellwig's book.  He trying to explain what that book says, in a limited amount of space.

Comment: @DavePhD: Interesting... So in fact Putanumonit should not be attacking Chochrane's 3% example, but should be attacking what is in the book ("economics professors who wrote a book").

Answer (score 10):

No.

Taking Bank of America for example, according to the [Bank of America Corporation 2017 annual financial report](https://tarahealthfoundation.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/BOAML_AR2017.pdf) (see especially Table 6 on page 39):

The value of all loans and leases was $937 billion while the value of deposits was $1,310 billion.

More broadly, the value of all assets (loans and leases being assets), after allowing for a $10 billion loss on loans, was $2,281 billion.

Liabilities, (deposits being considered liabilities) were $2,014 billion.

Shareholder equity was $267 billion.

So the ratio of equity to loans and leases was 267 / 937 = 28%

The ratio of equity to total assets was 267 / 2281 = 12%.

Comment: Certainly of interest (heh), but the claim was made in 2013.

Comment: @Roger http://media.corporate-ir.net/media_files/IROL/71/71595/AR2013.pdf for 2013, loans and leases were 928 billion and shareholder equity was 233 billion.  So 25%.